# How to add custom method to auto-generated class in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have a class with 2 methods as follow:

```
public class WorkManagement
{
    public string DoYourWork(Manager manager)
    {
        //
    }

    public string DoYourWork(Employee employee)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Manager and Employee are classes generated from database (in Entity Framework). I think it's ugly, for instance, when I need to extend more class, so I want to refactor this into:

```
 public interface IDoWork
 {
    string DoSomeWork();
 }

public class Manager:IDoWork
{
    public string DoSomeWork()
    {
        //
    }
}

public class Employee:IDoWork
{
    public string DoSomeWork()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But how I can deal with auto-generated classes? How I add these thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure the classes are partial classes that are generated, so you can extend the class by creating your own partial class for Employee/Manager.

Comment: @Phill: never know about that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Auto-generated code creates partial class.

```
public partial class Manager : EntityObject
```

So you just add one more file to the partial class like this:

```
public partial class Manager : IDoWork
{
   public string DoSomeWork()
   {
   }
}
```

[Reference to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456844.aspx).

[How to: Customize Generated Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738696.aspx)